# Write in a file if picture found in a folder

Tags: regex, bash, shell, csv

I have a csv file with in the **first column a list of product codes** made up by numbers and capital letters and in the **second column free space for the name of the picture** of the product of the first column.

I also have a folder with almost all the pictures but the codes of the pictures are substrings (edit: **prefixes**) of the product codes. The match between picture and product is one to many, so more that one products share the same picture.
Eg:

```
3234P3001 and 3234P3002 have the same picture 3234P30
```

I need to make a shell script that **scans the list of the codes in csv file and if there is a picture whose name is a substring of this code it writes that name of the picture in the second column**.

It's my first big project and I don't have experience in data manipulation.

Finding the maximum substring between the pictures is the picture of my product.

Comment: what ... have you tried

Comment: I don't know how to write it down

Comment: As there can be one code to many pictures, are there supposed to be multiple pictures listed in the 2nd column, or multiple rows of ( code, picture ) or is just finding the first one good enough?

Comment: @n0741337 For one product there are no more than one pics. Finding the maximum substring between the pictures is the picture of my product. My problem is lack of knowledge about the commands of reading and writing a file.

Comment: @eliosolutions - gotcha.  I didn't notice the relationship at first - that the product code is a prefix of the image name.

Comment: @n0741337 Yes I think it is. I'm sure 99%. Only sometimes there are some alterations before.

Comment: @eliosolutions You better make sure of the requirements. Usually, if the names can deviate, there's a better source of the relations (usually a relational database). Finding the right source ***always*** beats hacking your way through.

Comment: This is not [tag:data-mining]. I removed the tag spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does pretty much what you want.

Assuming your product codes are stored in a file called products.csv, if you save the code below in a file called "go", then do

```
chmod +x go
./go < products.csv
```

It may need a tiny bit of tweaking...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Cwd;

my $Debug=1;        # Set to 0 to turn off debug output
my $photosdir="/tmp";   # Or wherever your photos are

# Go to photos directory and load names of all JPEGs into array @photos
chdir $photosdir or die "Unable to chdir() to $photosdir\n";
my @photos=<*.jpg>;

# Debug - output photo filenames
print Dumper @photos if $Debug;

# Read product codes from our stdin
while(<>){
   chomp;
   my $product = $_ ;
   $product =~ s/;.*//;

   print "Finding photo for product: $product\n" if $Debug;

   # Run through all photo filenames and find longest match
   my $longestmatch=0;
   my $bestimage="<NONE>";

   foreach my $photo (@photos){
         # Strip extension off photo name
         $photo =~ s/\.jpg//;

         print "Assessing photo $photo\n" if $Debug;

         if($product =~ m/(^$photo)/ ){
            my $matchlength = length($&);
            if($matchlength > $longestmatch){
               print "Best match so far: $photo, ($matchlength characters)\n" if $Debug;
               $longestmatch = $matchlength;
               $bestimage = $photo . ".jpg";
            }
         }
   }
   print "$product,$bestimage\n";
}
```

Actually, you can do it a bit more elegantly and faster with a hash. Rather than looking through every one of thousands of photos till you find the longest match, just try seeing if the first n letters of your product are in the hash, if not try the first n-1 letters, then the first n-2 letters, like this. It should run much faster for large numbers of products and photos.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Cwd;

my $Debug=1;        # Set to 0 to turn off debug output
my $photosdir="/tmp";   # Or wherever your photos are

# Go to photos directory and load names of all JPEGs into array @filenames
chdir $photosdir or die "Unable to chdir() to $photosdir\n";
my @filenames=<*.jpg>;

# Now create hash of photonames without ".jpg" extension
my %photos;
for my $photo (@filenames){
   $photo =~ s/\.jpg//;
   # So if there was a file "xyz.jpg", $photos{"xyz"} will be defined
   $photos{$photo}=1;
}

# Debug - output photo filenames
print Dumper \%photos if $Debug;

# Read product codes from our stdin
while(<>){
   chomp;   # remove end of line
   my ($product,$field2,$field3) = split ";";

   print "Finding photo for product: $product\n" if $Debug;

   my $bestimage="<NONE>";  # Preset and overwrite if better one found

   # Keep removing last character of product till it matches a photo
   for(my $i=length($product);$i;$i--){
      my $short = substr($product,0,$i);
      print "Trying $short\n" if $Debug;
      if(defined($photos{$short})){
         $bestimage = $short . ".jpg";
         last;
      }
   }
   print "$product;$bestimage;$field3\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you solution, I'm getting an error Unable to chdir() to... Is it because I'm using Mac OS X?

Comment: Ok I've changed with "tmp" instead of "/tmp"

Comment: My csv is like this: 3234P3001;;aa but the script is not writing into the csv when finds the matches

Comment: Hello. Here you find the data on Dropbox, it is still uploading... https://dropbox.com/sh/xq2q0k4bwa25s6u/3C16EtdE2u

Comment: @eliosolutions The problem is likely that your .csv has strange (corrupted?) line ends (CR-only, which is neither UNIX nor DOS style). None of the tools I know handle this. If you fix it first, the script just works, and adds images to 326 out of 6468 lines in the sample data. See here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6330522/

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed the line ending, I've changed to unix and worked. Many thanks!

Comment: I've not tried yet your last solution but it sound's cool, in fact the first version took like 1 minute. Thanks again

Comment: This second version is great!

Comment: +1 I concur. The second version really hits a sweet spot of optimization/readability. I mean, I'd probably still have written the 5-line sed solution myself, but I can certainly endorse this answer. If not for performance, then for (way more) flexibility

Answer (score 2):

You could assemble a `sed` script on the fly, making a substitution for each image file that exists

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i -f <(
    find images/ -type f -name '*.jpg' | LANG=C sort -r | 
    while read imagename
    do
        basename=$(basename "$imagename" .jpg)
        echo "s#^\\($(printf "%q" "$basename")[^;]*;\\);#\\1$imagename;#"
    done) "$@"
```

Notes:

- the script is a dynamically compiled sed script
- I sort the filenames descending (so longest image names with a common prefix will be treated *first*)
- I scan the images directory only once (for performance, and also to be able to create predictable results)
- **updated**: now made the script actually handle images with common prefixes (e.g. `3234.png` as well as `3234P30.png`). The longest match will prevail - because of the `sort -r` step)

Example: For input file

```
3234P3001;;aa
3234P3002;;bb
```

Doing `script.sh input` will result in

```
3234P3001;/tmp/images/3234P30.png;aa
3234P3002;/tmp/images/3234P30.png;bb
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will try soon and let you know. The codes are 7k and the pics 1k so I don't know if it is better to scan the products and find a substring in the pics or scan the pics and find the products with the same prefix. What do you think?

Comment: I presented the solution as I'd make it :) Now, you'll have only one pass over the image files and only one pass over the input file. This is O(n+m) complexity.

Comment: Scanning the products O(n), and finding a substring in the pics would be O(m) (and actually worse, since you don't know what length prefix to look for at first... O(m*avg_suffixlength)), so that would lead to O(n*m*avg_suffixlength) with the constant involving IO, so not negligable. Bad plan with n*m ≅ 7k*1k ≅ 7m.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I will update you after I try it

Comment: Sorry the disturb could you please write me down a version for a csv with using semicolon instead of tab? All my files are in that format. Thanks

Comment: I've tried it but I'm not getting any data in the second column. I've put the file.csv the script and the tmp/images folder in the same folder. It runs the script but seems not finding any match.

Comment: @eliosolutions well... maybe there isn't any match? Or your files don't have `.png` extensions? (Note that all comparisons are case sensitive here). Without further information, I can't tell you what's happening - I did test it (as you can see from the displayed results)

Comment: the pics are .jpg and I've changed the code, could ? send you a small sample of the files? Maybe I'm missing something, btw I'me sure that more that one match exists.

Comment: @eliosolutions - yeah, just put it up somewhere (clean/healthy) and I might have a look

Comment: Hello. Here you find the data on Dropbox, it is still uploading... https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xq2q0k4bwa25s6u/3C16EtdE2u

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed the line ending, I've changed to unix and worked. Many thanks!

Comment: @eliosolutions In case you ran into the same problem with the longest prefixes not being used, the problem was that `sort -r` simply ignored the periods... (because of [locale-specific collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm)). I fixed that by adding `LANG=C` to the script. Now the `go` perl script and mine have the same results. Mine is more than **4x faster for this small dataset** though, and obviously shorter (30 lines of perl vs. 7 lines of bash)

Comment: From my laptop (Mac OS X) the solution of Mark Setchell ends in 3 secs against yours in more than 10 secs. I think your solutions are both very good and the one of Mark let me to do the task before yours today so I've chosen to select him for the answer, thanks both of you guys!

Comment: @eliosolutions Thanks for reporting success. I hadn't noticed that Mark posted an updated answer. The second approach looks like it should be faster indeed, since the sed script is nowhere near optimized. I think the perl variant could be more optimal, but likely, 3s is good enough :) **PS.** Just spotting a comment at the other answer: `sed -i` edits in-place

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified what your problem is or what you've tried, here's some pseudo-code to help you get started:

```
foreach line in csvfile {
   code = get first column(line)
   foreach filename in folder {
      if(filename is a substring of code) { 
         //match!
         write to file ("code, filename")
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, helpful pseudocode for focusing on the algorithm. My problem is lack of knowledge about the commands of reading and writing a file using bash or similar for unix.